# how to join multiple date columns into one in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the below dataframe with multiple date columns and its value :

```
date         value_1      date        value_2    date         value_3
01-01-1990   1            01-01-1990  2          02-01-1990   4
02-01-1990   3            03-01-1990  20         
                          04-01-1990  30
```

Output: combine all date columns into superset date column and show values accordingly.

```
date         value_1        value_2    value_3
01-01-1990   1              2          
02-01-1990   3                         4
03-01-1990                  20
04-01-1990                  30
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First is necessary deduplicated same columns names for pairs dates with values columns:

```
s = df.columns.to_series()
mask = df.columns.duplicated(keep=False)
c = np.where(mask, s + '_'  + (s.groupby(s).cumcount() + 1).astype(str) , s)
df.columns = c
print (df)
       date_1  value_1      date_2  value_2      date_3  value_3
0  01-01-1990      1.0  01-01-1990        2  02-01-1990      4.0
1  02-01-1990      3.0  03-01-1990       20         NaN      NaN
2         NaN      NaN  04-01-1990       30         NaN      NaN
```

Then loop by `groupby` with lambda function ans split by all pairs, create dates column, remove missing values and last [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) together:

```
dfs = [x.set_index(x.columns[0]).dropna() 
       for i, x in df.groupby(lambda x: x.split('_')[1], axis=1)]
#print (dfs)

df2 = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
print (df2)
            value_1  value_2  value_3
01-01-1990      1.0      2.0      NaN
02-01-1990      3.0      NaN      4.0
03-01-1990      NaN     20.0      NaN
04-01-1990      NaN     30.0      NaN
```

EDIT:

Answer was changed for datetimes columns and next 2 data values columns:

```
print (df)
  date_security  GH_LAST_PRICE Val  GH_VOLUME_PRICE Val date_security  \
0    01-01-1990                1.0                  7.0    01-01-1990   
1    01-02-1990                3.0                  8.0    03-01-1990   
2           NaN                NaN                  NaN    04-01-1990   

   DG_LAST_PRICE Val  DG_VOLUME_PRICE Val  
0                  2                 10.0  
1                 20                  NaN  
2                 30                  1.0
```

Create `MultiIndex`:

```
df.columns = [(np.arange(len(df.columns)) // 3).astype(str), df.columns]
print (df)
#              0                                                   1  \
  date_security GH_LAST_PRICE Val GH_VOLUME_PRICE Val date_security   
0    01-01-1990               1.0                 7.0    01-01-1990   
1    01-02-1990               3.0                 8.0    03-01-1990   
2           NaN               NaN                 NaN    04-01-1990   


  DG_LAST_PRICE Val DG_VOLUME_PRICE Val  
0                 2                10.0  
1                20                 NaN  
2                30                 1.0  

dfs = [x.set_index(x.columns[0]).dropna()
       for i, x in df.groupby(level=0, axis=1)]


df2 = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
#flatten MultiIndex
df2.columns = df2.columns.map('_'.join)
print (df2)
            0_GH_LAST_PRICE Val  0_GH_VOLUME_PRICE Val  1_DG_LAST_PRICE Val  \
01-01-1990                  1.0                    7.0                  2.0   
01-02-1990                  3.0                    8.0                  NaN   
04-01-1990                  NaN                    NaN                 30.0   

            1_DG_VOLUME_PRICE Val  
01-01-1990                   10.0  
01-02-1990                    NaN  
04-01-1990                    1.0
```

Comment: Thanks for this
I am getting error as :
InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects while doing concat with full ddata

Comment: @user3222101 - It means there are duplicated datetimes in some column. Is possible aggregate `mean` or `sum` for this values?

Comment: @user3222101 - Answer was chenged for this problem, please check it.

Comment: hey i checked - there were no duplicates in the date

Comment: @user3222101 - One idea - what return `print (df.columns.tolist())` after `df.columns = c` ?

Comment: DataError: No numeric types to aggregate - though i converted into float

Comment: my actual columns names looks like date_security , GH_LAST_PRICE  Val, GH_VOLUME_PRICE  Val, date_security, DG_LAST_PRICE  Val, DG_VOLUME_PRICE  Val -> do you think thiss might be causing problem

Comment: @user3222101 - exactly, this is problem. So there is only 6 columns?

Comment: in actual - 30 columns with 10 date_security in it

Comment: @user3222101 - OK, so need some time.

Comment: @user3222101 - Are data confidental?

Comment: yes :/ unfortunately so can't even copy column names

Comment: @user3222101 - Ok, so real data are like in sample - if missing value in datetimes, also missing in column for this datetimes? And second questin - for each datetime are 2 next data columns?

Comment: yes for each datetime there are 2 next columns And datetime has missing values in it like i showed in the example but there are no duplicate values present in the single date_security column.

Comment: @user3222101 - Please check next edit - rewrite last solution.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to stack date-value pairs vertically into a dataframe

```
df.columns = ['date_1', 'value_1', 'date_2', 'value_2', 'date_3', 'value_3']

>>> new_df = pd.concat([df[['date_1', 'value_1']].rename(columns={'date_1': 'date'}), df[['date_2', 'value_2']].rename(
columns={'date_2': 'date'}), df[['date_3', 'value_3']].rename(columns={'date_3': 'date'})]).dropna(how='all')

         date  value_1  value_2  value_3
0  01-01-1990      1.0      NaN      NaN
1  02-01-1990      3.0      NaN      NaN
2  01-01-1990      NaN      2.0      NaN
3  03-01-1990      NaN     20.0      NaN
4  04-01-1990      NaN     30.0      NaN
5  02-01-1990      NaN      NaN      4.0
```

and then do groupby

```
new_df.groupby('date',as_index=False).apply(lambda x:x.ffill().bfill().drop_duplicates())

           date  value_1  value_2  value_3
0 0  01-01-1990      1.0      2.0      NaN
1 1  02-01-1990      3.0      NaN      4.0
2 3  03-01-1990      NaN     20.0      NaN
3 4  04-01-1990      NaN     30.0      NaN
```